# How to set the maximum number of contacts with Dart engine?

Tags: physics, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am using dart as physics engine for Gazebo 9. I need to reduce the maximum number of contacts between two colliding body. In the sdf documentation, there is a “max_contacts” parameter which should set this. However, I suspect it only work with ode physics engine, because I tested different values with dart and there was no effect on the actual number of contacts.

How can I set the maximum number of contacts from a sdf file, if possible ? If it is not implemented, is there any plan for the implementation of this feature ?

thank you for your answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24082/how-to-set-the-maximum-number-of-contacts-with-dart-engine-?/) by [Clément Rolinat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18669/cl%C3%A9ment-rolinat/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I reported this on Gazebo issue tracker : [issue 2673](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2673/max_contacts-sdf-parameter-is-not-working)

edit : now that Gazebo is on github, the issue is here: [issue 2673](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2673)

---

Originally posted by [Clément Rolinat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18669/cl%C3%A9ment-rolinat/) with karma: 1 on 2019-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [awck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/37298/awck/) on 2020-12-07**:
Hi Clement, did you find a solution or workaround? Best, Alex

**Comment by [Clément Rolinat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18669/cl%C3%A9ment-rolinat/) on 2021-03-25**:
hello, sorry for the late answer, no the only "workaround" is to use the ode engine...